# HDD goes down and I need to reboot the raspberry

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive

I have a raspberry working with transmission + plex. The issue is that the HDD goes down randomly and those services stop to work. When that happens, the rasp is still alive and I can connect via ssh, but if I navigate to the path where the hdd is mounted the session goes down too.

Is there any place to see the logs, or any way to know what is happening to the hard drive??

Thanks.

PS: I am using raspbian.

## EDIT

As  Jaromanda X said I have used `dmesg` and one of the things I see is this:

```
[13392.666688] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[13637.654225] INFO: task scsi_eh_0:82 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[13637.654240]       Tainted: G         C      4.14.79-v7+ #1159
[13637.654247] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

It seems something wrong... isn´t??

## EDIT 2 *(the logs)*

**syslog**:

```
Feb  5 06:31:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt upgrade and clean activities...
Feb  5 06:32:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
Feb  5 06:32:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 32min 25.381396s random time.
Feb  5 06:32:01 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily-upgrade.timer: Adding 37min 12.722157s random time.
Feb  5 07:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[12282]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 07:26:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Session c3 of user pi.
Feb  5 08:16:29 raspberrypi minissdpd[370]: 1 new devices added
Feb  5 08:16:29 raspberrypi minissdpd[370]: 2 new devices added
Feb  5 08:16:30 raspberrypi minissdpd[370]: 6 new devices added
Feb  5 08:16:31 raspberrypi minissdpd[370]: 4 new devices added
Feb  5 08:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[13516]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 09:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[14660]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 10:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[15767]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 10:23:50 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Feb  5 10:23:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Daily apt download activities.
Feb  5 10:23:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 13min 18.894085s random time.
Feb  5 10:23:53 raspberrypi systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 9h 35min 38.781788s random time.
Feb  5 11:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[16798]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[17805]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Feb  5 12:24:11 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Timed out waiting for reply from 158.227.98.15:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Feb  5 12:24:21 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2001:720:1014:a205::2]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Feb  5 12:24:32 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2001:720:1014:a201::2]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Feb  5 12:24:42 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2001:720:1014:a202::2]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Feb  5 12:24:52 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Timed out waiting for reply from [2001:720:424:1::1:15]:123 (2.debian.pool.ntp.org).
Feb  5 12:24:52 raspberrypi systemd-timesyncd[263]: Synchronized to time server 178.255.228.77:123 (3.debian.pool.ntp.org).
```

Comment: `dmesg` will probably show you something ... and `/var/log` is full of logs

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX I have edited the message with the output of `dmesg`. Thanks.

Comment: that message doesn't really tell you WHY the HDD goes down, unfortunately - anything in /var/log?